# How do I bind multiple textures to multiple objects in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to draw a cube and a sphere and apply a different texture to each.

I use blender to create the scene and then export to an obj file which then includes the vertices, normals, uvs and faces for both objects as well as the textures.

I have created a routine which loads all the data from the obj file.  This all works as I can load the objects and display them etc but with only one texture.  As I say I have gone through pages and pages of code and posts and 99% only deal with 1 texture to 1 object and those that deal with multiple textures only deal with one object or are in a very old version of openGL.

The one thing I haven't tried is uniform sample2D arrays in the fragment shader but I haven't found an explanation on that so haven't tried it.

My code that I have below:

```
ObjLoader *obj = new ObjLoader();
string _filepath = "objects\\" + _filename;
//bool res = obj->loadObjWithStaticColor(_filepath.c_str(), _vertices, _normals, vertex_colors, _colors, 1.0);
bool res = obj->loadObjWithTextures(_filepath.c_str(), _objects, _textures);

program = InitShader("shaders\\vshader.glsl", "shaders\\fshader.glsl");
glUseProgram(program);

GLuint vao_world_objects;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao_world_objects);
glBindVertexArray(vao_world_objects);

//GLuint vbo_world_objects;
//glGenBuffers(1, &vbo_world_objects);
//glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_world_objects);

NumVertices = _objects[_objects.size() - 1]._stop + 1;
for (size_t i = 0; i < _objects.size(); i++)
{
    _vertices.insert(_vertices.end(), _objects[i]._vertices.begin(), _objects[i]._vertices.end());      
    _normals.insert(_normals.end(), _objects[i]._normals.begin(), _objects[i]._normals.end());
    _uvs.insert(_uvs.end(), _objects[i]._uvs.begin(), _objects[i]._uvs.end());
}

GLuint _vSize = _vertices.size() * sizeof(point4);
GLuint _nSize = _normals.size() * sizeof(point4);
GLuint _uSize = _uvs.size() * sizeof(point2);
GLuint _totalSize = _vSize + _uSize; // normals + vertices + uvs

GLuint vertexbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vSize, &_vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

GLuint uvbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &uvbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _uSize, &_uvs[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

TextureID = glGetUniformLocation(program, "myTextureSampler");

TextureObjects = new GLuint[_textures.size()];
glGenTextures(_textures.size(), TextureObjects);

for (size_t i = 0; i < _textures.size(); i++)
{
    // "Bind" the newly created texture : all future texture functions will modify this texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TextureObjects[i]);

    // Give the image to OpenGL
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, _textures[i].width, _textures[i].height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, _textures[i]._tex_data);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
}



for (size_t i = 0; i < _objects.size(); i++)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    }
    else
    {
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    }

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TextureObjects[i]);

    GLuint _v_size = _objects[i]._vertices.size() * sizeof(point4);
    GLuint _u_size = _objects[i]._uvs.size() * sizeof(point2);

    GLuint vPosition = glGetAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    if (i == 0)
    {
        glVertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    }
    else
    {
        glVertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(_v_size));
    }

    GLuint vUV = glGetAttribLocation(program, "vUV");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vUV);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer);
    if (i == 0)
    {
        glVertexAttribPointer(vUV, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    }
    else
    {
        glVertexAttribPointer(vUV, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(_u_size));
    }

    if (i == 0)
    {
        glUniform1i(TextureID, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        glUniform1i(TextureID, 1);
    }

}

_scale = Scale(zoom, zoom, zoom);
_projection = Perspective(45.0, 4.0 / 3.0, 0.1, 100.0);
_view = LookAt(point4(Camera.x, Camera.y, Camera.z, 0), point4(0, 0, 0, 0), point4(0, 1, 0, 0));
_model = mat4(1.0); // identity matrix
_mvp = _projection * _view * _model;

MVP = glGetUniformLocation(program, "MVP");
theta = glGetUniformLocation(program, "theta");
Zoom = glGetUniformLocation(program, "Zoom");

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
```

I understand that I have to switch between the active textures when drawing an object but I can't figure out how.

UPDATE

@immibis Ok I tried to do that yesterday but it didn't work but it was late and I was highly frustrated.  SO just to get my thinking correct here, do I have to create a buffer every time (glGenBuffer) and then fill it, activate texture and then glDrawArrays or do I just create the buffer and then fill it every time with the different vetices and uvs for each object, set the offsets and then call glDrawArray for each object?

When I tried this originally I didn't know where the 
glGetAttribLocation / glEnableVertexAttribArray /glBindBuffer
should go.  So if I understand correctly every time I do a transformation like rotating around the x axis then buffers have to be filled etc so the code needs to go in the display function.  Is that correct?

SOLVED
Ok so thanx to immibus' comments, it got me looking in a different direction.  I was staring the whole time into how the data was pumped into the arrays that I never even looked at glDrawArrays.  I was searching the web again and I came across a piece of code in a tutorial and the person explained glDrawArrays and I saw that you can tell it what to draw.

So then this became easy, as I originally thought it was supposed to be.  I changed my code back to pumping everything in the buffers and since I have a start and stop property on my objects returned from my loader it was real easy to tell glDrawArrays what to do.

Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with just binding the right texture before drawing each object? Also note that OpenGL doesn't care about objects.

Comment: Does the obj reader actually give you multiple objects? Unless you are using multiple textures for the same object, you should leave `glActiveTexture` set to `GL_TEXTURE0`.

Comment: The GL_TEXTURE0 part was part of the trying to get it to work I was doing. @immibis when you say drawing each object do you mean I am supposed to call glDrawArrays for each object meaning that each object is put into the buffers (vertices, normals, uvs) and then activate the texture and then call glDrawArrays?

Comment: @immibis the object reader populates 2 vectors of structures.  One struct is an object's data and the other is a texture's data.  I wrote this to work specifically with Blender object files so my arrays match up because the texture or material is listed for each object in the file.

Comment: @Dracosveen Yes, if you want multiple textures, you need multiple draw calls... or something more advanced like array textures or atlases.